# Is there a way to to align column contents at a certain character in the text (a dash for example)?

Tags: tables, spacing, align

I'm trying to create this section for my CV but I can't figure out how to align these table contents nicely. I want them all aligned at the "|" or em-dash.

This is the code I have now. It creates a table with 3 columns.

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section*{LANGUAGES}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X     
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
   }
      \textbf{English} (Native) & \textbf{French} & \textbf{Polish} \\ \\
      
    Speaking | \textit{Fluent} & Speaking | \textit{Limited} & Speaking | \textit{Proficient} \\ 
    
    Listening | \textit{Fluent} & Listening | \textit{Limited} & Listening | \textit{Proficient} \\ 
    
    Reading | \textit{Fluent} & Reading | \textit{Proficient} & Reading | \textit{Limited} \\ 
    
    Writing |  \textit{Fluent} & Writing | \textit{Intermediate} & Writing | \textit{Basic} \\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This is what it outputs.

[image: what I have now]

I would like it to output something like this

[image]

Where everything is aligned at the dash (but done in all 3 columns).

Is there a way to do that within the table? Can I make sub-tables within tables to do this or is there some kind of package for this?

Comment: Use at least 6 columns instead of 3, e.g., `\begin{tabular}{r@{---}lr@{---}lr@{---}l}` and then, e.g., `\multicolumn{2]{l}{\textbf{English}}` for the column heads. If this comment does not help, please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), than can be used to reproduce the output shown in the screenshot (currently I get something different with your code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `tabular*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% for less generous margins

\begin{document}

\section*{LANGUAGES}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l @{\ ---\ \extracolsep{0pt}} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l @{\ ---\ \extracolsep{0pt}} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l @{\ ---\ \extracolsep{0pt}} l
  @{}
}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{English} (Native)} &
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{French}} &
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Polish}} \\[2ex]
Speaking & \textit{Fluent} & Speaking & \textit{Limited} & Speaking & \textit{Proficient} \\
Listening & \textit{Fluent} & Listening & \textit{Limited} & Listening & \textit{Proficient} \\
Reading & \textit{Fluent} & Reading & \textit{Proficient} & Reading & \textit{Limited} \\
Writing &  \textit{Fluent} & Writing & \textit{Intermediate} & Writing & \textit{Basic} \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Note that an em-dash is ***not*** input as `|`. The fact that `|` may produce an em-dash is just incidental and, for instance, it would fail if you use T1 encoding. An em-dash is input as `---`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularx`, right - left aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                                 *{3}{r @{\ ---\ }
                                    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\itshape}X}
                                 @{}}
%
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{English} (Native)} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{French}} 
                &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Polish}}             \\[1ex]

Speaking    & Fluent    &   Speaking    & Limited       & Speaking  & Proficient    \\
Listening   & Fluent    &   Listening   & Limited       & Listening & Proficient    \\
Reading     & Fluent    &   Reading     & Proficient    & Reading   & Limited       \\
Writing     & Fluent    &   Writing     & Intermediate  & Writing   & Basic         \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]